# Can I use custom map image tiles with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-for-ee, mx-google-map

I need to display a Google Map with markers generated from Channel Fields, **using a custom map tile instead of Google's satellite imagery**. If I know where corners/points of my image map to exact lat/long coordinates, is there a way to load in my image to be the map image?

(A nice elegant "use my image as the map" solution would be great if there is one, but I'd be equally open to a hacky "stick my image on top of the map" sort of solution as well...)

Comment: I have never done this before, so I need to look into it. I am sure it's possible in some fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps api provides a way for you to supply your own image for the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe check out Stamen, which seems super cool. :)
http://maps.stamen.com